# Magento duplicated Menu

Tags: magento

Hy!

My problem is in this menu:
cambuistore.com.br/loja/index.php/

I would like others to explain why menu is duplicated in this case, because i have just one of this: getChildHtml('topMenu') ?> in my header.phtml

top.phtml & header.phtml - http://snipt.org/ujiH2

catalog.xml - http://snipt.org/ujiG8

needing any other files guys?

tks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the header block is defined twice in your layout XML?

It's impossible to tell without more information. Could you please edit your post to include your layout XML and the contents of your phtml files?

EDIT: Thanks

I've had a look over the files you've linked and I can't see any issues. The only thing I can think might be your problem is that elsewhere one of your .xml files is referencing "top.menu" and adding the block again.

In catalog.xml you have this:

```
<reference NAME="top.menu">
    <block TYPE="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.topnav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

top.menu is defined in page.xml like this:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
</block>
```

the type: core/text_list refers to the file at app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php, which goes through each of it's children blocks and renders them one by one.

If elsewhere in your xml (maybe page.xml, or something else) you're adding a top.phtml block to topMenu, then it will be rendering twice.

Let me know how you go.

Comment: in my theme layput folder i have this xml's:


catalog.xml


checkout.xml

customer.xml

j2tajaxcheckout.xml

magentoteam-cloudzoom.xml


magentoteam.xml

tag.xml

tempmela.xml

Just catalog.xml have Name="top.menu"

Comment: is there any other .xml than i have to check?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds like you've got a number of custom extensions there. I'd suggest turning them off 1 by 1 and seeing if any of that fixes the problem. When did you notice this first occurring? Does it occur if you turn the theme off and return to default?

Comment: Finaly i found a solution!

i have a duplicated menu in my base/default .xml and my site was calling the 2 xml's. Thanks a lot!